# Initialize WCF service before service starts?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've created an assembly containing WCF Services, which are declared in the app.config file of the assembly and are automatically hosted when I start to debug my client application. This all works.

Problem is, I need to run some initializations *before* the services are hosted, especially I need to collect a list of known types to be used with the [ServiceKnownType("RegisterKnownTypes", typeof(ServiceKnownTypesHelper))] attribute (I use MEF to collect the knowntypes from my assemblies, so I can't just put them in the config file, since they are known at runtime, not before).

Is there a way to initialize something **before** the WCF services are hosted? I can initialize stuff in the constructor of the service classes, but this is too late to register the known types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually encapsulated in derived `ServiceHost` where you can initialize anything before you host the service by overriding `OnOpening` method. You can also do some initialization without implementing a new `ServiceHost` by handling the `Opening` event on default `ServiceHost`.

Edit:

As you have already found the .config file generated for your service library is only used by test tool WcfSvcHost.exe. The application itself must have its own configuration in the main app.config / web.config so you can change the library config for debugging purposes as you need. There is no other way how to affect `ServiceHost` initialization in WcfSvcHost.exe.

Comment: I'm referring to the automatically started/hosted services when running the client app in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger while the WCF service project being in the same solution - where in the WCF service assembly, which is being hosted, can I find the service host? (for the standalone windows service this is no problem at all, there I can find the ServiceHost, but this does not help me for debugging).

Comment: In such case you cannot add custom initialization. The service is hosted in WcfSvcHost.exe tool and it is completely out of your control. It loads only service types from your assemblies to host them.

Comment: It just occured to me: since this is the wcf assembly, and the config file of this assembly never will be delivered to any customer, I can mess the config file up in any way I want. So I can just add those knowntypes to the config. Messy when they change, but since it is only for debugging thats ok.

Comment: Yes that's true. Post it as an answer.

Comment: @Sam: Ok, I did some conclusion.