# Initialize code before any WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have to host a WCF service (in IIS7.5, .NET 4.5.2), given a set of assemblies holding the service definition and its classes (request/response types).

Before any call is made to the WCF service, I want to initialize some code, how can I initialize this code even before the enduser (caller) hits the mex endpoint (to create sample requests in SoapUI for example, using the WSDL import).

Note that the WCF service page is shown nicely, but after import of the WSDL using SoapUI it looks like it uses reflection to discover the types; in this probe it hits code in the service library that needs some static lookup lists and these lists must be initialized)

Comment: "...I have to host a WCF service..." as in "self hosting a WCF service", i.e. not IIS? If so, you're in complete control already.

Comment: So you're asking to run code when a type is reflected instead of (static) instantiated? What is the difference between a type that is only reflected and when the initialization has run?

Comment: @rene: for me this was also very new, but it looks like the validation kicks off already during probing stage (to resolve the wsdl). Strange is that using the service page and then clicking on the ?wsdl link is showing the WSDL nicely

Comment: Can you enable full [wcf logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) and maybe use fiddler client side to see if Soap UI does some extra tricks?

Comment: Does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5856547/578411) help?