# Serilog WCF usage without constructors?

Tags: c#, wcf, serilog, app-code

I am new to c# and I am trying to using serilog in a WCF application.  This WCF application is hosted on IIS 6.0.

I need to create the logger once only when the service is initialized. However WCF does not seem to have constructors.  How can I create the logger below once only and have it available to the rest of the application. Any code examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                      .ReadAppSettings()
                      .CreateLogger();
              Log.Logger = logger;
```

I thought about using the AppInitialize in the App_Code folder but I cannot seem to get the program to trigger the AppInitialize method.

```
public class InitializeApp
{
    public static void AppInitialize()
    {
       
ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                      .ReadAppSettings()
                      .CreateLogger();
              Log.Logger = logger;
    } 
}
```

When I run the project in Visual Studio 2019  AppInitialize never gets hit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a function on WCF start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841635/running-a-function-on-wcf-start-up)

Comment: You can also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856090/initialize-wcf-service-before-service-starts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can do the constructor with WCF Service via some Dependency Inject library which supports WCF Service

You can use [AutoFac.WCF](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/wcf.html#services) then you can register type of ILogger by [Autofac](https://autofac.org)

```
builder.Register<ILogger>((c, p) =>
{
    return new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadAppSettings()
                 .CreateLogger();
}).SingleInstance();
```

Second, About the  "InitializeApp" of the application. there are couple ways to do it.

1. Add *Global.asax* file and then you can write the code in *Application_Start*
2. Use [Owin Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) to write own pipeline. You can write your code in Startup.cs
3. Use [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator), you can write *PreApplicationStartMethod* and *PostApplicationStartMethod* (extension for Global.asax)